# opening a pdf from ubuntu terminal by piping a 'locate' result

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can find a file using the locate command as in
`locate 'file.pdf'`
Is it possible to pipe that result to the xdg-open command?
I tried

```
xdg-open | locate file.pdf
```

but no success. Also just a simple `open file.pdf` would not work on my terminal.
Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Try `xdg-open "\`locate 'file.pdf'\`"` or `find . -exec grep file.pdf {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

The first of Harrymc's comment-examples can be "better" written as
`xdg-open $(locate file.pdf | head -n 1 )`, and then
`locate file.pdf | head -n 1  | xargs xdg-open`
will do the same, as long as you have ONE file.pdf
`head -n 1` will pick only the first found file.pdf, if locate happens to find more than one.